# Multiple Checkbox Values PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I've got this code, anyone help on making it work...

```
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

    $image_name = $fetch['image_name'];
    $image_location = $fetch['image_location'];


    <img src="'.$image_location.'"/>

    <input name="image['.$image_id.'][6x7]" type="checkbox" value="'.$image_name.'" /> 6x4
    <br />
    <input name="image['.$image_id.'][8x9]" type="checkbox" value="'.$image_name.'" /> 7x5

}
```

**Display on different page...**

```
foreach($_POST['image'] as $image_id => $name) {

    $uploaded[] = $name;

    echo''.$name.'<br />';


    foreach($name as $size => $size) {

        $uploaded[] = $size;

        echo''.$size.'<br />';

    }
}
```

**Input Script**

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES('', '$name', 'size')");
```

I am uploading both image name and size (from the checkboxes 6x4, 7x5) 
I am able to input the **size** into the database but **image name** just says **Array**.

I know this is an obvious fix but I just can't get my head around the **multiple arrays** is the checkbox values!

Any help of feedback is welcome! HELP!

Comment: Please can you show an examples of your insert query?

Comment: How about you post all of your code exactly as you have it? There is no way that what you have posted does what you're describing (or anything, for that matter)

Comment: Please note that mysql_ functions are deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your $image_location and $image_name are fine so you have correct values on your checkboxes? Otherwise we would need some more details..

Try below to display that correctly then (you're using multidimensional array):

```
foreach($_POST['image'] as $image_id => $image) {

    foreach($image as $size => $name) {


        $uploaded[] = $name;
        echo''.$name.'<br />';


        $uploaded[] = $size;
        echo''.$size.'<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Mateusz, Yes I am getting the $image_location no problem and am able to insert that into the database.

My issue is simply with $name and $size - which I am still having trouble with, unfortunately your solution didn't work (but thanks for helping)

Comment: Can you post what you have on var_dump($_POST['image'])?

Comment: array(2) { [2]=> array(1) { ["6x4"]=> string(38) "image1.jpg" } [3]=> array(1) { ["6x4"]=> string(39) "image1.jpg" } } image1.jpg
6x4
image1.jpg
6x4
Home

Answer (score 1):

```
<input name="image['.$image_id.'][]" type="checkbox" value="6x7" /> 6x4
<br />
<input name="image['.$image_id.'][]" type="checkbox" value="8x9" /> 7x5
```

The value should not be the image name, but the size you specified. You already have the image ID, so why include the filename? You can just extract that from your database again...

Also:

```
foreach($name as $size => $size) {
```

... is a bit weird: Using the $size var for key and value? That's asking for trouble. ;)

Comment: `$size => $size` is not "a bit weird", it is just plain wrong. `$size` will be the be the index, not the related value (which I'm sure is not what is wanted). There is so much wrong with the posted code that I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: I know its wrong! If it wasn't wrong I wouldn't be on here, would I (!!)